# How can I specify a CSS tag for not disabled and hover on a button?

Tags: html, css

I am trying the following:

```
button:disabled {
    border-color: #50a3c8 #297cb4 #083f6f;
    background: #0c5fa5 url(/Content/images/old-browsers-bg/button-element-bg.png) repeat-x left top;
    .top-gradient( #FFF, #72c6e4, 4%, #0c5fa5);
    color: white;
}

button:not(disabled):hover {
    border-color: #1eafdc #1193d5 #035592;
    background: #057fdb url(/Content/images/old-browsers-bg/button-element-hover-bg.png) repeat-x left top;
    .top-gradient(#FFF, #2bcef3, 4%, #057fdb);
}
```

But my IDE is saying that "disabled" is not a valid HTML tag however just for the second CSS definition where disabled is enclosed in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `:not(:disabled)`

http://jsfiddle.net/yVanF/

Just for a bit more clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/yVanF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use **:not(:disabled)**

```
button:not(:disabled):hover {
    border-color: #1eafdc #1193d5 #035592;
    background: #057fdb url(/Content/images/old-browsers-bg/button-element-hover-bg.png) repeat-x left top;
    .top-gradient(#FFF, #2bcef3, 4%, #057fdb);
}
```